# gcc not giving warning even with -Wall flag

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, posix

I call the function `timer_settimer` with an argument of type `timer_t*` (a pointer) or `timer_t` and gcc compiles both versions. Doesn't give any error or nothing else.

```
void initialize_timer(timer_t * tid, int seconds)
    ...
    timer_settime(*tid, 0, ts, NULL) == -1;
    OR
    timer_settime(tid, 0, ts, NULL) == -1;
```

No error  no nothing. (the first version works correctly. the second bugs).
This is my Makefile:

```
all: 
    gcc -Wall -ggdb -lrt  -pthread -o jenia_thread thread.c
```

How can I make gcc output all the warnings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that it doesn't have a prototype of the function? Where is the prototype of `timer_settime`?

Comment: its in the pthread library

Comment: @Floris Even if it doesn't see a prototype, it should warn, since the types passed to durind the second call don't match the - assumed - implicit declaration in the first call.

Comment: Are you sure your `initialize_timer` is compiled? Try changing `ts` by `bla` and recompile to be sure.

Comment: yea. it didnt compile:thread.c: In function ‘initialize_timer’:
thread.c:164:5: error: ‘ts’ undeclared (first use in this function)
thread.c:164:5: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
thread.c:161:26: warning: unused variable ‘blabla’ [-Wunused-variable]
make: *** [all] Error 1

Comment: Why do you get the `ts` error, could you fix this first?

Comment: Then to be sure you don't have something like `#define timer_settime(x, y, z)` to empty, could you check the output of the preprocessor (using `gcc -E`)?

Comment: nono. its ouah that asked me to see if my code is compiled at all. so i changed "ts" to "blabla" to show that the compiler compiles this

Comment: is used the -E flag, and it didnt output anything. 
in other words, -E didnt change anything.

Comment: @JeniaIvanov Now go back and read how to use the `-E` flag...

Comment: Do you have `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` before `#include`ing any headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `timer_t` is defined as `void*`.  Specifically, on my system, I have:

```
typedef void * __timer_t;
...
typedef __timer_t timer_t;
```

(You have to go several levels deep in system include files to find this; I compiled a small program with `gcc -E` to see the preprocessed source with all the includes expanded.)

Your system most likely has something similar, particularly if you're using the GNU C library.

The first parameter of `timer_settime` is of type `timer_t`, or `void*` -- which means that an argument of *any* pointer-to-object or pointer-to-incomplete type will be implicitly converted to `void*` and not require a compile-time diagnostic.

It's an unfortunate choice, and one that doesn't seem to be imposed by POSIX. You'll just have to be careful to pass an argument of the right type without any help from the compiler.